# Animation hide imageview [Titanium]

Tags: view, colors, hide, titanium-mobile

I have created an imageView in Titanium and now I would like to hide it using an fade out animation along with changing the backgroundColor of the view.

I have the following code

```
var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'test.png',
    width:10,
    height:10,
    top:100,
    left:205
});

image.animate({
    curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT, 
    opacity:10, 
    duration:200
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`opacity`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-opacity) attribute is a floating point value from 0.0 (completely transparent) to 1.0 (completely opaque). Try this code instead, to fade out the image.

```
// This code block will fade out the image to invisible
image.animate({
    curve:Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT, 
    opacity:0.0, 
    duration:200
});
```

Alternatively, if you just want to hide the view, without animation, just use the [`hide()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-hide) and show() methods.

Comment: Curves such as Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT are not supported on Android. This code will work for Android but it requires omitting the curve.